# Abrir janela e clicar automaticamente em algum lugar

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, blogger

Olá eu gostaria de quando as pessoas que entrarem no meu site,clicarem em um determinado botão abrir meu canal do youtube e automaticamente se inscrever.poderia me fornecer algum codigo?

Answer (score 0):

Tente criar um link no botão para `https://www.youtube.com/subscription_center?add_user=USUARIOYOUTUBE`, preferencialmente com `target="_blank"` para abrir em nova aba.

Comment: faz um ai pra mim não estou conseguindo

Comment: como ficaria completo

Comment: <a href="https://www.youtube.com/subscription_center?add_user=descealetra" target="_blank">Meu Canal</a>

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa ser mais especifico, no entanto uma forma possível é esta.

```
<a href="#seulinkdoyoutubeaqui" target="_blank">Meu Canal</a>
```